# batch file label running for 30 seconds

Tags: batch-file

I program to both learn how and to make fun files for jokes and tricks. I'm trying to make a batch file that will run a label inside the batch file for a set amount of time like 30 seconds without having to use a for-do statement. what I have so far is shown below and is reduced to a small test, but uses a for-do statement.

```
@ echo off

for  /l %%a in (1,1,10) do (
  call :matrix)

echo Thanks for using the MATRIX
pause

:matrix
echo %random%%random%
```

Comment: Hint: [timeout](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)

Answer (score 1):

use `timeout` command, it can set amount of time like 30 seconds without having to use a for-do statement.

```
@ echo off

for  /l %%a in (1,1,10) do (
  call :matrix)

echo Thanks for using the MATRIX
timeout 30 

:matrix
echo %random%%random%
```

if you don't want to show count done message, you can use `timeout 30 >nul`

Answer (score 0):

this starts a second `cmd` process (minimized), that simply does a `timeout 30`. It's existence is the signal to repeat the loop.

```
@echo off
start /min "MyTimer" timeout 30
:loop
echo %random%%random%
tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq MyTimer" | find "Console" >nul && goto :loop
```

Sadly, `tasklist` doesn't give useful errorlevels, so we have to use `find`.

Note: for debugging purposes you may want to remove the `start` switch `/min`.